# Using a Table of Authorities as a Glossary in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

I followed these instructions http://shaunakelly.com/word/layout/glossary.html.  { TOA \c "1" \p \e "**three_tabs**" }

I still see the dot leaders.  I also tried inserting a TOA by clicking on the "Insert Table of Authorities" icon and choosing the format: None for tab leader, but it still displays.

Comment: Do you see the dot leaders in the TOA field itself or just in the result? When I first went through this procedure, I found that fixing the tabs in the Table of Authorities style only fixed the TOA field that I already had. If I inserted a new TOA field, it had the dot leader problem again. So more investigation, perhaps.